# Material UI - TreeView datastructure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to structure the data that I get from a server, so I can use the `TreeView` component from `Material UI`: https://material-ui.com/api/tree-view/

I'm fetching large amounts of data so I want to fetch child nodes from the server when the user clicks on the expand button. So
when the first node is expanded a HTTP request is sent to a server which returns all of the children of that node. When another node is expanded the children of that node is fetched etc.

On startup of the page I want to fetch the root node and its children. The JSON returned will look something like this:

```
{
 "division": {
 "id": "1234",
 "name": "Teest",
 "address": "Oslo"
 },
 "children": [
   {
    "id": "3321",
    "parentId": "1234",
    "name": "Marketing",
    "address": "homestreet"
   },
   {
    "id": "3323",
    "parentId": "1234",
    "name": "Development",
    "address": "homestreet"
   }
 ]
}
```

When expanding the `Marketing` node I want to make a HTTP call to fetch the children of this node. So I would get JSON like this:

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "id": "2212",
      "parentId": "3321",
      "name": "R&D",
      "address": "homestreet"
    },
    {
      "id": "4212",
      "parentId": "3321",
      "name": "Testing",
      "address": "homestreet"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I am confused on how to create such a data structure which can later be used my the `TreeView` component. How can I create such a structure?

Comment: It's all nested `<TreeItem>`s. The `children` array translates exactly to an array of `<TreeItem>`s. Each item needs to know its id so it can request its children from the server when clicked. All you really need to do is render `this.props.children.map(item => <MyTreeItem {...item} />)` where `MyTreeItem` is your custom version expanding the original with a fetch call.

Comment: @ChrisG so do I have one `MyTreeItem` per node?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Did you check out the [example](https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/#tree-view)?

Comment: Yes, I've seen that example.
My only thought is that, I at some point need to make some kind of `if-else` check on if a node has been expanded before. If it has not I want to make a call to the server. If it has been opened, closed, and then opened again I don't want to fetch server data again, but use the fetched data from before. Would your suggestion make this possible?

Comment: Of course, that's just `state`. The fetch call will populate `this.state.children`, so opening the node will simply check if that's empty.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Would it be to much to ask if you could make a small example?

Comment: I'm certainly willing to debug _your_ code, but just hand working code over for free, not so much

Comment: Okay. I have started on the implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-ix5wg
But I'm confused on a few things:
1. How to display the JSON which should be displayed at startup
2. How to render the `TreeItems` with the data

Comment: @ChrisG could you help with the problems stated above?

Comment: I took a look, and the main thing you need is to properly simulate the API that delivers the nodes. Then pass the id to each item so each can load its children. I could help but don't see how other than to write the entire thing for you.

Comment: Okay, thanks i'll figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone still looking for a solution to this problem I've recently tackled it using a combination of the `selected` and `expanded` props in the [TreeView API](https://material-ui.com/api/tree-view/). See this [Code Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/tree-demo-krxn3) for an example of how to asynchronously load new children and expand their parent once they are loaded.

```
import React from "react";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";

const mockApiCall = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const nextId = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
      resolve([
        {
          id: `${nextId}`,
          name: `child-${nextId}`,
          children: []
        },
        {
          id: `${nextId + 1}`,
          name: `child-${nextId + 1}`,
          children: []
        }
      ]);
    }, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1000));
  });
};

export default class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: [],
      selected: "1",
      tree: new TreeNode({
        id: "1",
        name: "src",
        children: []
      })
    };
  }

  handleChange = async (event, nodeId) => {
    const node = this.state.tree.search(nodeId);
    if (node && !node.children.length) {
      mockApiCall()
        .then((result) => {
          this.setState({ tree: this.state.tree.addChildren(result, nodeId) });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({
            selected: nodeId,
            expanded: [...this.state.expanded, nodeId]
          });
        });
    }
  };

  createItemsFromTree = (tree) => {
    if (tree.children.length) {
      return (
        <TreeItem key={tree.id} nodeId={tree.id} label={tree.name}>
          {tree.children.length > 0 &&
            tree.children.map((child) => this.createItemsFromTree(child))}
        </TreeItem>
      );
    }
    return <TreeItem key={tree.id} nodeId={tree.id} label={tree.name} />;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <TreeView
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        selected={this.state.selected}
        onNodeSelect={this.handleChange}
        expanded={this.state.expanded}
      >
        {this.createItemsFromTree(this.state.tree)}
      </TreeView>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying with this example.  In my case while loading the initial data I need to fetch from API. So how can I do the changes in the constructor part. Could you please help me.

Comment: Hi @Ganesh if you need to load the entire tree up front that is not possible from the constructor. If you are using React functional components it can be done in a `useEffect(() => { ... // make api call here }, [])` or with class components (like the answer) you can use `componentDidMount` I believe. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried to set the state in componentDidMount as you suggested but its not working.

Comment: I tried to create Treenode in **componentDidMount** with my api response using setState. Failed to update.

Comment: @Ganesh the example is assuming you are opening the nodes in a tree one-by-one, not loading them all at once at the beginning. It might be best to open a new question on Stack Overflow for your code.